# Difference ruby-1.9.2 and ruby 1.9.2-mri with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

What is the difference between `ruby-1.9.2` and `ruby 1.9.2-mri` with rvm. Are they the same ruby?

When I do an `rvm list` I get this:

```
 rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p431 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p180-mri [ x86_64 ]
```

I recall that MRI is Matz Ruby Interpreter. Is this only in 1.9.2 version? Why is it there and what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be specific to your installation (maybe you installed 1.9.2 at one point with a custom name?), since `rvm list` just lists your locally-installed Rubies. All the rubies you listed are MRI Rubies. Here's the output of `rvm list known` which will display all available Rubies to install:

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.6-head
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p334]
[ruby-]1.8.7-head
[ruby-]1.9.1-p378
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.1-head
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p180]
[ruby-]1.9.2-head
ruby-head
```